# jquery, how to know div is hidden?

Tags: jquery

I have code that uses jquery.slideup and jquery.slidedown

How can i know that div is hidden?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

To see if an element is visible or not, you can use the [*visible selector*](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible) with the [*is*](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/is) function:

```
$("#idElement").is(":visible") // true or false
```

But sounds to me like you want to toggle the slide effect, for that you can use the [slideToggle](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideToggle) function.

Comment: I could be wrong, but thats .is(":visible") (with the colon)?

Comment: thanks for answer, nice to know there is something like .is function

Answer (score 23):

```
$('#id').is(':hidden');    //true if is hidden
$('#id').is(':visible');   //true if is visible
```

But you may want to use slideToggle for your needs.

Comment: watch the quotes there - you have $("#id') where you mean $('#id').

Answer (score 2):

You can use the visible selector:

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible

Answer (score 0):

You could use $("#elementID").height() == 0 since you know it is either going to be up or down. It may be faster than doing the .is(":visible") as well but I haven't done any testing on that fact.

Answer (score 0):

HTML CODE:

when you click on div id "collapse"  if the the div id "flex-container"  is visible then its hide and if hide then visible.

```
          <div  id="collapse" >collapse</div>
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#collapse").on('click', function() {

   if($('#flex-container').is(':visible'))
    {  $("#flex-container").hide();  }
    else 
    {  $("#flex-container").show();  } 

   });
 });
```